# Using Intent.ACTION_VIEW together with DocumentFile class

Tags: android, file, android-intent, uri, documentfile

I use this code to achieve "Open in" function for File Class (java.io.File):

```
...
MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExtension);

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type); // Standard File class            
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "blabla"));
...
```

I would like to do the same with DocumentFile class (android.support.v4.provider.DocumentFile):

```
...
MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExtension);

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(documentFile.getUri(), type); // DocumentFile class          
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "blabla"));
...
```

However, It seems no application (even on Android 5) is able to handle URI - **documentFile.getUri()**.

Do I do anything wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(docFile.getUri(), type);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Comment: Yes, it really works! With one bizarre exception regarding video files (there is no video, only audio track plays), however it can be related to who know what. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, I spent some time trying to make it work. I've only tried it with images, so no idea.